When calling window.print() in Chrome, how can I fix the issue where it behaves unexpectedly only on the first print?
When calling window.print() in Chrome, how can I fix the issue where it behaves unexpectedly only on the first print?
This issue has been occurring for about a month. It doesn't happen in Naver Whale browser but does occur in Chrome and Edge. When window.print() is called for the first time, it behaves unexpectedly. How can I resolve this issue?
Naver Whale chromium version 126 useing
I'm using Angular, and the parameters required for printing are passed through the URL. When window.print() is called for the first time, the print preview window opens, but the URL gets reset, causing an issue. From the second print onwards, it works as expected. How can I resolve this issue?
label.component.ts
 async ngOnInit() {
        this.QRwidth = 50;
        const dlvyDto = new MakrDlvyOrdGroupNoDto();
        dlvyDto.ordNoList = this.invoiceIds;
        this.orderDetails = await 
        this.rest.postDlvyPrint(dlvyDto).toPromise();
        this.printService.onDataReady();
    }

print.service.ts
onDataReady() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.print();
        this.isPrinting = true;
        this.router.navigate([{outlets: {print: null}}]).then(console.info);
    });
}


What exactly is the issue? You say that the print window opens and the URL is reset, but what exactly "doesn't work"?

@Verity The URL has been reset, so the intended HTML print area is not displayed. Instead, the current page is shown in the preview.
The first time, the URL was valid before the preview window opened, but once it opened, the URL was modified with the parameters removed. The second time, it worked correctly.
ex )
a valid URL for printing : localhost:4200/test(print:print/printLabels/S1/14788)
first : localhost:4200/test(print:print/printLabels/S1/14788) -> localhost:4200/test
second : localhost:4200/test(print:print/printLabels/S1/14788)
